# make in hex from unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have a piece of code like

```
unsigned char *tag = NULL;
tag = (unsigned char *)malloc(8);
memset(tag, 0, 8);
memcpy(tag, (const char *)"50C59390",8);
```

I have to send it as length 4. So I am trying to convert it in 4 byte hex like 0x50C59390.

```
unsigned char * buffer = (unsigned char *)calloc(4, sizeof(char));
int index,j = 0;
for(index = 0 ; index < 8; index++)
{        
    buffer[j] = (tag[index] & 0x0F) | (tag[++index]>>4 & 0xF0);
    printf("%02X", buffer[j]);
    j++;
}
```

I am trying above code. but its not working as required.

Comment: here tag is just name of variable

Comment: Can you explain the premise for your claim that the "length of tag is 4" in your first piece of code?

Comment: @vikky its not clear what code is supposed to do. do you want to interpret string as hex and convert to integer? then your question is already answered or do you want to pack Hex string such that each `unsigned char` holds 2 hex digits?

Comment: @GauravDhiman yes I want to pack Hex string such that each unsigned char holds 2 hex digits. That is why apply bitwise operator

Comment: @vikky Well each `char` has ASCII value and for numbers and lower case letters (hex) its between 48-57 and 97-102, so unless you check it and subtract it from `char` you can't pack 2 raw ASCII values in 1 char

Comment: So, you have as input a string with eight characters and as output a 32-bit unsigned integer? This thing is called parsing and you'll find lots of info on that topic easily. If you want to roll your own and have problems, you need to extract and provide a [mcve], as usual.

Comment: The expression `(tag[index] & 0x0F) | (tag[++index]>>4 & 0xF0)` results in undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: Take a look at `strtol()`

Comment: Please don't edit questions in ways that invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just copy ascii characters as hex values. You need to convert them.

Something like:

```
unsigned char convert(unsigned char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        return ch -'0';
    }

    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
    {
        return ch -'a' + 10;
    }

    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
    {
        return ch -'A' + 10;
    }

    return 0; // or some error handling
}
```

and use it like:

```
for(index = 0 ; index < 8; index = index + 2)
{   
    buffer[j] = convert(tag[index]) << 4;
    buffer[j] += convert(tag[index+1]);

    printf("%02X", buffer[j]);
    j++;
}
```

See it online here: https://ideone.com/e2FPCT

Comment: @vikky Answer updated as first version had a number of bugs....

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am not exactly sure whether you try to convert to or from a string. However, if you have C++11 available, you can use [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for easy conversion:

```
int hex_value = std::stoi(tag, nullptr, 16)
```

Note how the third argument of `std::stoi()` denominates the base (in this case 16 for hexadecimal).

Comment: You're right, I've updated the post.